# STM32 F746 and nuttx - Ethernet-Networking won't compile

Tags: stm32

Has anyone successfully got NuttX and Ethernet running on
the STM32F746ZG? As soon as "networking" is enabled, the
make-process fails with
"undefined reference to 'arm_netinitialize'".

On an f743zi NuttX with networking runs without any issues.
Before I continue searching for the error, I thought I'd ask here
if anyone has managed to get it working before.

I just want have the eth-network enabled on the h746zg.

Comment: so you have a call to a function, that doesn't exist - undefined reference is usually that. Have you investigated in what .c/.cpp it happens? Does function with this name exist? Is it properly included everywhere it needs to be used? Maybe it needs to be forward-declared?

Comment: stm32f7/stm32_ethernet.c:void arm_netinitialize(void) is declared several times in nuttx.  in "nuttx/arch/arm/src/stm32f7/stm32_ethernet.c:void arm_netinitialize(void)" for example. but I'm shut sure, if iit is the workling one for the f746zg.  so i would like to know if anyone has already got nuttx to work with the f746.

Comment: keep digging. You found where the function is. Now you need to find where in other code it's referenced without being included there.